# Why is my python code is running fine on command prompt but not running in sublime?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

When I'm running simple print("Hello") on command prompt it is successfully running. But on the sublime text editor, it is showing the below error. I have also installed the python3 package in sublime.
Please help me out through this!

```
'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: py -3 -OO -u "C:\Users\reeda\Dummy.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\reeda]
[path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\windows\SysWOW64;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\reeda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\reeda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Users\reeda\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\reeda\AppData\Roaming\npm]
```

Comment: I dont have sublime installed, but you can see in `shell_cmd` that its running "py" instead of  "python", maybe you have somewhere in the settings to change what command is running

Answer (score 0):

1. in Sublime press Ctrl+Shift+P (linux command in ST for 'goto anything')
2. Type in 'install',**
3. click on 'sublime package control: install package'.
4. Then select SublimeREPL. It will install it automatically.
5. To use it go to Tools>sublimerepl>python from the menus.
   (or you configure for Ctrl + B for open easily)

Comment: It's running in sublimREPL. Thanks! But why is it showing the error in its default interpreter though?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime probably can't find where python is installed. You just have to add it to your path like so:

C:>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.9;%PATH%

C:>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib

C:>python